# LEFT OUTER joins in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).joins(:blog).select
```

which is meant to find all posts and return them and the associated users and blogs.
However, users are optional which means that the `INNER JOIN` that `:joins` generates is not returning lots of records.

How do I use this to generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead?

Comment: See also [LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4/35363012)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id").
              joins(:blog).select
```

Comment: what if you only wanted the Posts which had no user?

Comment: @mcr `@posts = Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.user_id").joins(:blog).where("users.id IS NULL").select`

Comment: Doesn't select need a param? Shouldn't this be `select('posts.*')`?

Comment: In Rails 3, this is the only way to have true control over your joins and know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 75):

You can do with this with `includes` [as documented in the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations):

```rb
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {visible: true})
```

Results in:

```sql
SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, ...
       "comments"."updated_at" AS t1_r5
FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
WHERE (comments.visible = 1)
```

Comment: From my tests `includes` does not do a join, but a seperate query to get the assosiation. So it avoids N+1, but not in the same way as a JOIN where the records are fetched in one query.

Comment: @Kris You're right, in a way. It's something you need to watch out for because the `includes` function does both, depending on the context that you're using it in. The Rails guide explains it better than I could if you read the entirety of section 12: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: This only partly answers the question because `includes` will generate 2 queries instead of a `JOIN` if you don't have a need for the `WHERE`.

Comment: This will generate a warning in Rails 4 unless you also add `references(:comments)`. Additionally, this will cause all returned comments to be eager loaded in memory due to the `includes`, which is possibly not what you want.

Comment: If you put this code in a scope and for some reasons add later a .joins(:comments), the LEFT OUTER JOIN will be converted into an INNER JOIN...

Comment: To make this even more "Railsy": `Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {visible: true})`. This way you also don't need to use `references`.

Answer (score 11):

I'm a big fan of the [squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel#joins):

```
Post.joins{user.outer}.joins{blog}
```

It supports both `inner` and `outer` joins, as well as the ability to specify a class/type for polymorphic belongs_to relationships.

Answer (score 10):

Use `eager_load`:

```
@posts = Post.eager_load(:user)
```

Answer (score 8):

By default when you pass `ActiveRecord::Base#joins` a named association, it will perform an INNER JOIN. You'll have to pass a string representing your LEFT OUTER JOIN.

From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

> `:joins` - Either an SQL fragment for additional joins like "`LEFT JOIN
>   comments ON comments.post_id = id`" (rarely needed), named associations
>   in the same form used for the `:include` option, which will perform an
>   INNER JOIN on the associated table(s), or an array containing a
>   mixture of both strings and named associations.
>
> If the value is a
>   string, then the records will be returned read-only since they will
>   have attributes that do not correspond to the table‘s columns. Pass
>   `:readonly => false` to override.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [left_outer_joins](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) method in activerecord. You can use it like this:

```
@posts = Post.left_outer_joins(:user).joins(:blog).select
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in Rails 3, which is what the poster is asking for.

Comment: Correct; this was introduced in Rails 5.0.0.

Answer (score 4):

Good news, Rails 5 now supports `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Your query would now look like:

```
@posts = Post.left_outer_joins(:user, :blog)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :friends, :foreign_key=>"u_from",:class_name=>"Friend"
end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end


friends = user.friends.where(:u_req_status=>2).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.u_id = friends.u_to").select("friend_id,u_from,u_to,u_first_name,u_last_name,u_email,u_fbid,u_twtid,u_picture_url,u_quote")
```