# Querying many to many relation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an app where users could rate books. Tables are users(id), books(id) and rating(user_id, book_id, value). I've made these models

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end
```

I want to get a list of all (both rated and unrated) books with their ratings made by current user. It's easy in SQL with outer join but I can't figure out a way to do it in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [LEFT OUTER joins in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3) you'll have to specify the outer join in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

it's quite simple in rails too. You probably should add a relationship in user with books as well.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :users, :through => :ratings
end

current_user.books.includes(:ratings).all
```

should work.

Comment: This will return only rated books, while I need all of them