# How can I do a LEFT OUTER JOIN using Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I don't have any ideas. Could you give me any clues (like reference sites). Any help will be appreciated.

```
Model1: GROUP(id, name)
Model2: USER_GROUP_CMB(id, user_id, group_id)
```

Expected SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM groups AS g LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group_cmbs AS cmb 
            ON g.id = cmb.group_id
WHERE cmb.user_id = 1
```

I tried to set up associations below but I dont know what to do after this.

```rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_group_cmb
end

class UserGroupCmb < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group
end
```

Rails Version: 3.1.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER joins in Rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3)

Comment: Use [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#joins) (See [LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35363012/165673))

Comment: There's an out-of-the-box solution for Rails 5! See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35592251/1323144) below...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe an `includes` will use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query if you do a condition on the table that the `includes` association uses:

```
Group.includes(:user_group_cmb).where(user_group_cmbs: { user_id: 1 })
```

Comment: Doesn't work here (Rails 3.2.7): using a condition on an `includes`-referenced relation raises a `StatementInvalid` exception, complaining it misses a `FROM-clause entry`. I need to add an explicit call to `join`, which defaults to being inner.

Comment: What are your thoughts about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025429/rails-how-can-i-do-left-outer-join-on-activerecord/14599174#answer-14599174 ?

Comment: If you're worried about filtering, then define another association that links to the same class and which applies the filtering for you.

Comment: If you really hate strings and like symbols and hashes (not rockets), you can do ```Group.includes(:user_group_cmb).where(user_group_cmbs: { user_id: 1})```

Comment: Or: `Group.eager_load(:user_group_cmb).where('user_group_cmbs.user_id = ?', 1)`. `eager_load` always performs left join (while `includes` performs two separate queries instead by default). But be careful using left join generated with `includes` or `eager_load` since it can break custom `select` clause.

Comment: @marksiemers I love ActiveRecord for this. (Question is edited too)

Answer (score 20):

Rails 5+ allows you to do the following:

```
Group.left_outer_joins(:user_group_cmb)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_joins

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in rails 3.x regardless if you are referencing the table or not in a where clause:

```
Group.eager_load(:user_group_cmb)
```

...and it will perform a left outter join

Answer (score 8):

It might be quite important to mention that [using includes](http://searls.testdouble.com/2013/01/26/an-includes-trap/) has possibly unwanted side-effects.

> if the filtered association is subsequently scoped, all of the
>   original filtering disappears
>
> As it turns out, by scoping on the filtered association we’ve lost any
>   filtering-as-side-effect that we attained from includes. And it’s not
>   because of how we searched, either.

Make sure to read the complete article and alternatively there's [a gem for that](https://github.com/elabs/ar_outer_joins).

Answer (score 8):

The problem with the accepted answer is that it will actually do a `LEFT INNER JOIN` technically because it won't display entries where the `user_group_cmbs. user_id` is null (which would be the reason to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`).

A working solution is to use [`#references`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references):

```
Group.includes(:user_group_cmb).references(:user_group_cmb)
```

Or the even more convenient [`#eager_load`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/eager_load):

```
Group.eager_load(:user_group_cmb)
```

Read the more detailed explanation [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html).

Answer (score 7):

Use a custom joins statement:

```
Group.joins("left outer join user_group_cmbs as cmb on groups.id = cmb.group_id")
  .where("cmb.user_id = ?", 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) if you just need to link users to groups.  Use [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) if you need to store additional membership information.

**Example:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users      
end
```

Comment: Exactly, I must concern about User as you said. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't comment to an earlier answer because well I don't have 50 reputation.
But here's how it worked for me when I ran into below error

> includes-referenced relation raises a StatementInvalid exception, complaining it misses a FROM-clause entry. I need to add an explicit call to join, which defaults to being inner.

I had to use .references and mention the table name or for it get added to the FROM-clause