# Left outer join with conditions on Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to performe left outer query with conditions. ActiveRecord, as I read, doesn't allow to make what I want. I try this:

```
Platform.where(url: urls).includes(:campaign_platforms).where.not('campaign_platforms.campaign_id = ?', campaign.id)
```

and get "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'campaign_id' in 'where clause'..."

**UPD:**

```
 class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :campaign_platforms
   has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_platforms
   has_many :posts
   has_many :screenshoots
   belongs_to :platform_category
   belongs_to :user
 end


 class CampaignPlatforms < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :campaign, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :platform, dependent: :destroy
 end


 class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaign_platforms
    has_many :platforms, through: :campaign_platforms
 end
```

Comment: make sure `campaign_id` column exists in your `campaign_platforms` table

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: it exist for sure, as I mentioned, this is AR doesn't allow to make such query.

Comment: Try: `Platform.joins(:campaign_platforms).where(url: urls).not(campaign_platforms: {campaign: campaign.id})`

Comment: @User089247, Nope, NoMethodError: undefined method `not' for #<Platform::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fba00fc69c8>
As I understood from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-join-in-rails-4 it must be SQL query in joins

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: can you try this,

 Platform.joins("as p left outer join campaign_platforms as cp on p.id = cp.platform_id").where("...")

Comment: @User089247 I want to select platforms that exist in Platform table, that have url from urls variable (given by app), but doesn't belongs to given Campaign (throught campaign_platforms). My last non working attempt:
Platform.where(url: urls).joins("left join campaign_platforms ON platforms.id = campaign_platforms.platform_id WHERE campaign_platforms.campaign_id != 195")

I use Rails 4.1

Comment: Umm.. @misa - try this: `Platform.joins('LEFT OUTER join campaign_platforms ON campaign_platforms.platform_id = platforms.id').where(url: urls).where.not('campaign_platforms.campaign_id = ?', campaign.id)`

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord provides you the ability to specify the `JOIN` conditions in the `joins` method.

```
Platform.joins('JOIN campaign_platforms ON platforms.id = campaign_platforms.platform_id JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = campaign_platforms.campaign_id').where('campaign_platforms.campaign_id <> ? AND url IN ?', campaign.id, urls)
```

That means you can change a `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or whatever you want.

Most of the people tend to use crazy workaround to avoid writing a single fragment of SQL. Don't be scared. ActiveRecord is not intended to completely replace SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use `eager_load`

```
Platform.where(url:urls).eager_load(:campaign_platforms).where.not('campaign_platforms.campaign_id = ?', campaign.id)
```

I have tried `left_outer_joins` but it threw out an undefined method error.

And it works like charm if your want to display all the Campaign which does not have a campaign platform.

Answer (score 0):

Soluction

```
#controller
@search = Box.distinct.select('boxes.*, people.first_name, people.last_name').includes(:street, :block).order('boxes.created_at DESC')
                  .left_outer_joins(orders: [{user: :people}])
                  .page(params[:page]).ransack(params[:q])
 @boxes = @search.result

#view
<% @boxes.each do |box| %>
<tr>
   <td><%= box.number %><%=box.first_name %><%=box.last_name %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```