# Sort users based on most recent response to a particular answer in a survey?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, psql

I'm trying to sort users based on their most recent response to a certain question in a survey using Rails 5, PostgeSQL 9.4.5

So far I've got:

```
User.includes(responses: [answer: :question]).where(questions: {id: X}).order(...)
```

Not sure what to put in the order. The responses all have numerical 'scores' representing which answer it is. I'm imagining something at the end like:

```
.order("answers.score ASC")
```

But I'm struggling to get the two to attach. I only want to sort the Users by their most recent answer to that specific question. (They can take the survey multiple times)
I'm assuming I need to set a string function in some `SELECT`, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the actual SQL of the rails query like this:

`User.includes(responses: [answer: :question]).where(questions: {id: X}).to_sql`

Then you can `order` by the right *table.field* (find the table name in the SQL returned by `to_sql`) and the field in `db/schema.rb`

It should be a `created_at`. `User...order('responses.created_at DESC')`

**UPDATE**

But this will sort all `responses` and not `users` by their last response on question, as you've commented below.

In this case you have to:

1. group the users by their responses
2. calculate the last response(MAX(user_responses.created_at)) for each user
3. sort the users by last response

Something like this:

```
User
  .includes(responses: [answer: :question])
  .where(questions: {id: X})
  .group('users.id')
  .order('MAX(responses.created_at) DESC')
```

Comment: That works on the basic idea, however, that sorts by ALL `responses` from each user. I want to filter the `responses` down to a specific question, and then order the Users only by those- rather than all of them.

Comment: Wow! That actually worked. I had to add a `references(:responses)` and a few more values to the `.group`, but otherwise it was a success!

Comment: The only issue now is that it loses the Users that have not yet answered the Survey. Do you know of a way to include that? That was the original goal for using the `includes`, but it might make this query a little crazy.

Comment: Try to replace the `includes` with a custom [`joins` using LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24358856/5802769)

Comment: Not having much luck with that. Running into some syntax errors writing the pure SQL out. Doesn't `includes` simply do a basic `LEFT OUTER JOIN` under the hood?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you can check the SQL code _under the hood_ with the `to_sql` method

Comment: Right. I've done that, which is why I was saying- if I were to do a custom JOINS, I would do it the same way that `includes` does it, so what difference would the custom one make or need to be?

Comment: > I wouldn't recommend this for has_many relationships, but it works great for has_one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130053/discussion-between-marius-zaharie-and-rockster160).