# Rails count number of instances key/value pair shows up in array, and append the count to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, where-clause, store

```html
  def index
     tag_array=[]
     courses = current_user.studio.courses
     courses.each do |a|
         tag_array << a.age_tag.id
         tag_array << a.level.id
         tag_array << a.category.id
      end
      @tags=current_user.studio.tags
      tags.each do |d|
        e=tag_array.where(:id => d).count
          d.store("count",e);
      end
          
  end
```

I'm looking for a way in rails to count the number of times the key/value pair of :id => d shows up in an array, then append it to a value in an each statement. Rails keeps throwing errors saying that .where and .store are not valid functions.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

`.where` is an `activerecord array` method and not simple array method..
In your case, you can..

```
def index
  tag_array = current_user.studio.courses(:age_tag, :level, :category).map do |a|
    [a.age_tag.id, a.level.id, a.category.id]
  end.flatten
  count_hash = current_user.studio.tags.map do |t|
    ["count_#{t}", tag_array.count(t)]
  end.to_h
end
```

Comment: Will still result in a n+4 query

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pluck the columns with:

```
Studio.left_joins(courses: [:age_tag, :tags, :level, :category])
      .where(id: current_user.studio)
      .pluck('age_tags.id, levels.id, categories.id, COUNT(tags.*)')
```

`.left_joins` is new in Rails 5. See [LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4) for Rails 4.

Comment: Maybe yours is correct...i am still confused what does OP is expecting..I just tried to solve syntax error..