# Listing users and the association is optionally present if they have a record for the current day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model and another model that tells me the time they "checked-in" to work.

```
User
- id
- name

Checkins
- user_id
- timestamps
```

So in my User model I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :checkins
end
```

What I want to do is on a page display a list of users, and IF they have a checkin for the current day then the 'checkin' association should be present, otherwise null.

```
@users = User.find_todays_checkin()
```

So I have to basically perform an outer join I guess?

```
select *
from users u
  outer join checkins c on u.id = c.user_id
where c.created_at = '2017-10-21'
```

A user may or may not have a checkin for the current day, if they do, the checkin association should be non-nil, otherwise nil.

How can I do this query using active record?

Comment: U have amazing reputation on SO which tells us you only can answer such question. Why ?????  It's so basic.   For name sake???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking, but you could accomplish something similar with a scoped association.  Add this to your `User` model:

```
has_many :todays_checkins, class_name: 'Checkin',
  -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day) }
```

Calling `todays_checkins` on a user record will return associated checkins for the current day.  For example:

```
User.first.todays_checkins   # User's checkins for today or nil
```

You could iterate through all users and output today's checkins as follows:

```
@users = User.all.includes(:checkins)
@users.each { |user| puts user.todays_checkins }
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to be able to do this dynamically, you can change `checkins` association on the fly by adding a class method to you `User` model:

```
def self.find_todays_checkins
  User.has_many :checkins,
    -> { where created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day }
end
```

Now, running `User.find_todays_checkins` will modify your `checkins` association to only show today's checkins.  You would have to write a similar revert the association back to its original scope.  Of course, this affects the entire `User` class.  I am not quit sure how to localize this to one ActiveRecord association.