# left join is not returning proper information

Tags: mysql, sql, activerecord

I have a table `courses` and a table `volunteer_rosters`. `courses` contains a list of all courses and `volunteer_rosters` contains a list of volunteers teaching/assisting on the course.

I want to write a query that returns a list of all courses that do **not** have any volunteers assigned to it. This is what is happening:

```
courses     
-------     
id 
 1  
 3  
 4  
 5  
 6  

volunteer_courses
-----------------
id 1 course_id 1  
id 2 course_id 1  
id 3 course_id 1  
id 5 course_id 3  
id 6 course_id 3
```

All of the below queries are returning
**course_id 3**
course_id 4
course_id 5

Why is course_id 1 (correctly) being left out, but course_id 3 is not???

```
Course.joins("LEFT JOIN student_rosters ON courses.id = student_rosters.course_id where student_rosters.course_id is null")

Course.joins("LEFT JOIN student_rosters ON courses.id = student_rosters.course_id").where(student_rosters: {id: nil})

Course.includes(:student_rosters).references(:student_rosters).where(student_rosters: {id: nil})

Course.includes(:student_rosters).references(:student_rosters).where('student_rosters.id = ?', nil)

Course.joins("LEFT JOIN student_rosters ON courses.id = student_rosters.course_id").where(student_rosters: {id: nil})
```

Same exact question, but none of the solutions are working for me:

[LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4)

Comment: Can you write a working query in regular sql, without all this activerecord stuff?

Comment: This is the query that every query above generates: `SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" LEFT JOIN student_rosters ON courses.id = student_rosters.course_id WHERE "student_rosters"."id" IS NULL
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `join`. Try this:

```
select id from Courses
where id not in (select course_id from volunteer_courses)
```

Comment: Brilliant, I love nested selects. This should have come to me...however learning how to write good sql queries in active record is killing me slowly....for anyone who needs this query in active record I kind of just hacked it because I can't be bothered spending the time learning it.

`Course.where('id not in (select course_id from volunteer_rosters)')
`

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no need to use `join`s, using `not in` is dangerous with a subquery.  It does not do what you really want.  If any row in the subquery returns a `NULL` value, then the outer query returns nothing.  No rows at all.

For this reason, I strongly recommend using `not exists` and avoiding `not in` with subqueries:

```
select c.id
from Courses c
where not exists (select 1 from volunteer_courses vc where vc.course_id = c.id);
```

Or the `left join` version:

```
select c.id
from Courses c left join
     volunteer_courses vc 
     on vc.course_id = c.id
where vc.course_id is null;
```

In addition, both of these can take advantage of an index on `volunteer_courses(course_id)`.

Comment: I tried your first example

`SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE (not exists (select 1 from volunteer_rosters where role = 0))`

and it did not work, it returned nothing while there indeed are rows that should have returned.

Comment: @Yitzhak . . . The query in your comment and the version in my question are not at all the same.