# Rails left outer join with row including NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to do a complex outer join. I wanna have a row in the result for the `service interval` if there is no `service_note` that's connected to it. As you see from the query `service_interval` belongs to one `service_job` which is connected to service_notes through the joint table `service_note_jobs`. At the moment it returns an empty relation if there is no `service_note` connected to that `service_interval`.

```
def self.distance_and_time_until_next_service(service_interval_ids)
  ServiceInterval
    .left_joins(vehicle: { service_notes: :service_note_jobs })
    .where(
      'service_note_jobs.service_job_id = service_intervals.service_job_id AND '\
      'service_intervals.vehicle_id = service_notes.vehicle_id'
    )
    .where(service_intervals: { id: service_interval_ids })
    .group('service_intervals.id')
    .select(
      'service_intervals.id',
      "MAX(GREATEST(service_notes.odometer, service_intervals.created_odometer) - vehicles.odometer + service_intervals.distance_interval) AS distance_left_until_next_service",
      "MAX(ROUND(EXTRACT(epoch FROM(GREATEST(service_notes.date, service_intervals.created_at) - NOW())) / 86400  + service_intervals.time_interval)) AS time_left_until_next_service"
    )
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this after your left_joins:

```
.where(vehicle: { service_notes: { id: nil } })
```

Or more general sample

```
User.left_joins(:posts).where(posts: { id: nil })
```

This will give you users with no posts.

Comment: Wouldn't this filter out the ones with service notes?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will filter out records with service_notes. You will get only ones without them.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem, it should also keep the ones without service notes. I just realized that COALESCE might work.