# Left outer join using ruby on rails (>=6) ORM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there a way to simply do a left outer join using rails ActiveRecord?

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358805/left-outer-join-in-rails-4) there are some ways using raw SQL, but I'd like to use the 'rails way' (presuming there *is* a rails way)

i.e. a query to retrieve the records represented by the maroon area:

[image]

Why not use raw SQL (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24358839/5783745)) - that's a fair question. My app has no raw sql, only syntax of the form `customer.purchases` so I'd like to keep the code consistence across the app.

Answer (score 1):

Rails >= 5 appears to have this capability built in.

[Here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins)'s a simple example:

```
User.left_outer_joins(:posts)
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id"
```

[Here](https://bigbinary.com/blog/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5)'s another example:

```
Author.left_joins :posts, :comments

# Produces:
Author Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "authors".* FROM "authors" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."author_id" = "authors"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."author_id" = "authors"."id"
```

This [example](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) from RailsGuides is also handy to know (although it contains some raw SQL):

```rb
Customer.left_outer_joins(:reviews).distinct.select('customers.*, COUNT(reviews.*) AS reviews_count').group('customers.id')

#Produces:
SELECT DISTINCT customers.*, COUNT(reviews.*) AS reviews_count FROM customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON reviews.customer_id = customers.id GROUP BY customers.id
```