# Same query on Rails and SQL return different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need help in converting this SQL to ActiveRecord query.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(total_sales.start_date) AS maximum_start_date,
  customers.external_id, product_categories.external_id AS product_category_id
FROM
  total_sales
INNER JOIN 
  customers
ON
  customers.id = total_sales.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
  product_categories
ON
  product_categories.id = total_sales.product_category_id
WHERE 
  (customers.organization_id = 1)
GROUP BY
  customers.external_id,
  product_categories.external_id
```

I tried doing

```
TotalSales.joins(:customer).includes(:product_category).
  where("customers.organization_id = ?", 1).
  group("customers.external_id, product_categories.external_id").
  maximum(:start_date)
```

and it generates almost the query I want. This is what it generates:

```
SELECT
  MAX("total_sales"."start_date") AS maximum_start_date, 
  customers.external_id, product_categories.external_id AS customers_external_id_product_categories_external_id
FROM
  "total_sales"
INNER JOIN "customers" ON
  "customers"."id" = "total_sales"."customer_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_categories" ON
  "product_categories"."id" = "total_sales"."product_category_id" 
WHERE
  (customers.organization_id = 1)
GROUP BY
  customers.external_id, product_categories.external_id
```

But this returns on Rails:

```
=> {"DIA"=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, "MES"=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, nil=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014}
```

If I run that query on DB console, it returns

```
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.1";"DIA"
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.1";"MES"
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.1";""
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.10";"DIA"
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.10";"MES"
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.10";""
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.100";"DIA"
"2014-01-01";"CLIENTE.100";"MES"
...
```

and this is what I want. On DB console it works, but on Rails it doesn't. :(

Comment: Here is an example of the working query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a6d1/1/0. The same doesn't work on Rails..

Comment: guess it's the OUTER LEFT JOIN vs LEFT JOIN that's generating the behavior. Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025429/how-can-i-do-a-left-outer-join-using-rails-activerecord Also look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins One way might be to drop the where and to filter after you get the records, depending on the record set size

Comment: Both queries with or withour the OUTER produces the desired output on DB console. It seems the problem is how AR is transforming it on a hash.

Comment: I believe it's related to the fact that both group by columns have the same name..

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in Rails. If you change your line with the `group` from:

```
group("customers.external_id, product_categories.external_id").
```

to:

```
group("customers.external_id", "product_categories.external_id").
```

it works. **NB! that you should use two strings separated with comma.**

Must be when Rails are rendering the result from SQL it thinks that the group is only one field if it's in one string, although it builds a correct SQL query.

You will have this result instead:

```
=> {["CLIENTE.1", "DIA"]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, ["CLIENTE.1", "MES"]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014,
    ["CLIENTE.1", nil]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, ["CLIENTE.10", "DIA"]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014,
    ["CLIENTE.10", "MES"]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, ["CLIENTE.10", nil]=>Wed, 01 Jan 2014, ...}
```

I assume that you know how to use it.

A little tip, use `Arel` to avoid "hard code" table names, you can use this:

```
cust = Customer.arel_table
prod = ProductCategory.arel_table
TotalSales.joins(:customer).includes(:product_category).
  where(cust[:organization_id].eq(1)).
  group(cust[:external_id], prod[:external_id]).
  maximum(:start_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

*includes != LEFT JOIN*

You should not use `includes(othertable)` when you want your query somehow depend on `othertable`, as `includes` it has a different semantic.

With includes you just say ActiveRecord that you intent to get the objects from othertable soon, so it should optimize for it. But it is object-oriented. You get `TotalSales` objects in your example.

A join is a relational database thing, where the column of tables can be mixed. We normally do not do such things in object world. That why this often gets difficult.

If you need a left join, you need to tell rails so. According to the rails guide, you do need to use a SQL fragment.

```
TotalSales.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.id = total_sales.product_category_id')
...
```

See also my answer to this question: 
[Rails 4 Relation is not being sorted: 'has_many' association w/ default scope, 'includes' and 'order' chained together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896215/rails-4-relation-is-not-being-sorted-has-many-association-w-default-scope/32916669#32916669)