# :joins | change behavior inner join to left join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, left-join

I have two tables 'users' and 'lms_users'

```
class LmsUser
    belongs_to :user
end

class User
    has_one :lms_user
end
```

When I write `User.all(:joins => :lms_user)` it joins tables with **Inner join**.

I want a **Left join**. How can change this behavior? (I don't want to use SQL commands, only Ruby syntax for this.)

How can I handle this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please run a search on SO before asking a question. Here is your answer on how to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3

Comment: @ChrisPeters: OP said he wouldn't like to use SQL syntax.

Comment: @MladenJablanović: Link that I posted to clearly shows that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull off LEFT JOIN without SQL, using `includes`, but only if you specify additional constraint (or merely an `order` clause) which involves a column from joined table(s). So,

```
User.includes(:lms_user).all
```

won't generate LEFT JOIN (but two separate queries instead), but

```
User.includes(:lms_user).where(:lms_user => {:role => 'admin'}).all
```

would.

More about this on

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html (see eager loading section)
- http://ruby.ryanbigg.com/post/1468788928/left-outer-join-with-arel

Answer (score 0):

`:joins => "LEFT JOIN lms_users ON lms_users.user_id = users.id"`

Comment: Did you forget the "left outer" part?

Comment: basically I don't want to use sql sytex.

Answer (score 0):

`User.left_outer_joins(:lms_user)` if You are on rails 5+