# rails multiple outer joins syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models

user

```
has_many :leave_balances
```

leave_balance

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :leave_type
```

leave_type

```
has_many :leave_balances
```

I want to output a table format showing user names and their balance by leave type.
Not every user can have every balance i.e. outer joins required.

I'd like to see something like this:

```
Employee   Annual Leave   Sick Leave
Bob        10 
Fred                      9
Sara       12             15
```

I am unsure how to get this out as a single statement?

I am thinking something like User.joins(:leave_balances).joins(:leave_type)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a hash to `joins` method for [nested joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level)

so you'll do

```
User.joins(leave_balances: :leave_type)
```

But that will perform an `INNER JOIN`, and I think that what you need is an `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

so you might have to manually write the `join` as [described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced this exact same thing. I switched to Squeel and I am *much* happier now. Specifically, the syntax for specifying an outer join is very clean:

```
result = User.joins { leave_balances.outer.leave_type.outer }.where { some_constraints }
```

https://github.com/ernie/squeel