# rails query - conditional joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have 4 tables A, B, C & D as follows:
`B belongs to A`
`B belongs to C`
&
`C has many D`

As 'A' may or may not have any B's but if there is a B, then that B must have a C. And according to my logic, C will have at least one D or may be more.
Now, I want to get the list of A's with count(b) as well as count(d). Here count(b) and count(d) might be zero.

So what I was doing till now is as follows:
`@a = A.joins(bs: {c: :ds}).select("a.*, count(b) as count_b, count(d) as count_d").group("a.id")`
But eventually this is not working, as it `INNER JOIN` `b` with `a`. Which means, if there is no corresponding `b` for `a`, then that `a` will not be in the list `@a`. That's the problem.

So, is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Left outer join:
`@a = A.joins("LEFT JOIN B on A.id=B.a_id INNER JOIN C on C.id=B.c_id INNER JOIN CD on C.id=CD.c_id INNER JOIN D on D.id=CD.d_id")`

For more details check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661804/activerecord-query-all-and-include-association-which-meets-condition/32661913?noredirect=1#comment53502423_32661913)

Comment: You are right. It would have worked if there were only A and B. But I don't know, which join to apply b/w B-C, C-CD & CD-D. I hope, I have not been ambiguous in explaining.

Comment: Can you try the modified solution ( and tell me if didn't work what was the problem )

Comment: Actually I tried it earlier but it didn't work. I tried `@a = A.joins("LEFT JOIN B on A.id=B.a_id LEFT JOIN C on C.id=B.c_id LEFT JOIN CD on C.id=CD.c_id LEFT JOIN D on D.id=CD.d_id")` instead which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`joins` has a form where it accepts a string. In that string you can put `'LEFT OUTER join bs ON bs... = as...'`

Comment: I tried writing `A.joins("LEFT JOIN B on A.id=B.a_id LEFT JOIN C on C.id=B.c_id LEFT JOIN CD on C.id=CD.c_id LEFT JOIN D on D.id=CD.d_id")`. But, that didn't work for me...

Comment: You are right. It would have worked if there were only A and B. But I don't know, which join to apply b/w B-C, C-CD & CD-D. I hope, I have not been ambiguous in explaining.

Comment: Sorry but where did you get a `CD` table?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. CD is join table b/w C and D, as C and D are many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I tried
`@a = A.joins("LEFT JOIN B on A.id=B.a_id LEFT JOIN C on C.id=B.c_id LEFT JOIN CD on C.id=CD.c_id LEFT JOIN D on D.id=CD.d_id")` which worked for me.