# Rails: Order activerecord object by attribute under has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
class Post
  has_many :commments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I wish to display a list of `posts` ordered by date of `post` creation (`submitted_at`). I also want some `post` xyz to appear at the top if it has some new comment posted and yet to be reviewed by moderator. We will determine this by a `boolean` attribute/field at comments level (moderated = 1/0)

I tried

```
Posts.join(:comments)
  .distinct
  .order("submitted_at DESC, comments.moderated")
```

but this excludes posts that have no `comments` and results aren't sorted as expected. I am sure that we can do this at ruby level, but looking for a way to do this using AR.

Comment: How about using "include" instead of "join"

Comment: may be this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

For the join, use this:

```
Posts.join("LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id")
```

Which will include the ones with no comments.

Your sorting seems to suggest you want a count of moderated comments, in which case, try this:

```
.order("submitted_at DESC, COUNT(comments.moderated)")
```

Although, you may need to use `group` in some way too.

Comment: I don't need the count. I just want the posts with comments yet to be moderated at the top. Could count help me here?

Comment: Ah. Is moderated a boolean field?

Comment: yes.. but in db its stored as 0/1 as per rails convention.