# Query an association with an alias

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `users` table and a `tasks` table with a model with the following association:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: User
end
```

I'm trying to build a query that will search the `task`'s `description` and its `owner`'s name as such:

```
includes(:owner).where("LOWER(tasks.description) LIKE ? OR LOWER(owner.name) LIKE ?", "%#{q.downcase}%", "%#{q.downcase}%")
```

...but I don't know how to properly query the users table for the task owners. In place of `owner.name`, I've tried `users.name`, `tasks.users.name`, and probably a few other things, all to no avail. How can I do this?

Note: I do not want to add a gem for this. I'm looking for a solution that is native to rails.

EDIT:

The foreign key as it exists in my schema.rb

```
add_foreign_key "tasks", "users", :name => "tasks_owner_id_fk", :column => "owner_id", :dependent => :nullify
```

SECOND EDIT:

I also need a solution that will return an AREL. I can get this to work by returning an array of objects, but I need to add other query methods to the result, so it has to be AREL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a foreign_key of owner_id if you want to call owner.name in your view or query.

Second, you should be able to still call user, but since it's a belongs_to, it would be user.name, not users.name

If you set up the foreign_key you can call owner.name like you did before and it will work.

This should help you set it up:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys

Comment: The foreign key already exists - see my edit above. As for using `user.name` rather than `users.name`, note that this is inside a query, and so is referencing a table name, not an activerecord association method.

Comment: hit save by mistake

Comment: try this:   includes(:owner).where("LOWER(tasks.description) LIKE ? OR LOWER(tasks_owner_id_fk.name) LIKE ?", "%#{q.downcase}%", "%#{q.downcase}%"

Comment: What's the error?  Cause I use foreign keys in a few models and I mimicked your query and it worked for me.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tasks_owner_id_fk"
LINE 1: ...E (LOWER(tasks.description) LIKE '%and%' OR LOWER(tasks_owne...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116511/discussion-between-michael-cruz-and-dtakeshta).

Comment: I was finally able to find a solution. See my answer if you are curious. Thanks for putting some time into helping!

Answer (score 0):

After digging around all day, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245201/left-outer-joins-in-rails-3) helped me out, and my solution is the following:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = tasks.owner_id").where("LOWER(users.name) LIKE ? OR
       LOWER(tasks.description) LIKE ?",
       "%#{q.downcase}%", "%#{q.downcase}%")
```